# Is this a correct usage: 'all expenses met by foundation'

Tags: phrase-request

I attended a course abroad. It was an expensive course, but my school's foundation paid for everything. It was a reward for some tests.
I want to mention this in my CV. How can I state it in a formal form?

Answer (score 1):

You may consider the following as part of your overall paragraph:

'All expenses were paid for by my school's foundation.'

I add 'my school's' for better identification.

Answer (score 1):

It's common to phrase it as "all expenses paid". E.g. "The foundation awarded me an all expenses paid course". This phrasing emphasizes how generous the reward is, and presumably your intention is to draw attention to the fact that your test scores were so good that you not only got into the course, but didn't have to pay for it, so this wording is good for that.